# Is there a way to change Tabbar images and action from embedded ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have 5 ViewController that embedded with TabbarController. I created a class Tabbar to customize my Tabbar like :

```
class Tabbar: UITabBarController,UITabBarControllerDelegate {

var tabBarIteam = UITabBarItem()

@IBOutlet weak var tabbar: UITabBar!

 override func viewDidLoad() {

     super.viewDidLoad()
                        // THIS IS FOR FİRST TABBAR ITEM
   let selectedImage1 = UIImage(named: "vitrin_active")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    let deSelectedImage1 = UIImage(named: "vitrin_deactive")
           tabBarIteam = self.tabBar.items![0]
           tabBarIteam.image = deSelectedImage1
           tabBarIteam.selectedImage = selectedImage1

  .... I HAVE ALSO 4 MORE.
}
```

In my firstViewController , There is a button action

```
    @IBAction func ChangeTabbarimageAndAction(_ sender: Any) {
    ..
}
```

I want to change `Tabbar` images and actions (like push) when FirstView's `ChangeTabbarimageAndAction` tapped. Is this possible? If yes, How could I do? I searched in SO but can't find any solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change action in delegate method of tabbar

```
 class yourclass: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate {
        func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
            print("push or present action")
        }
    }
```

And for setting the image you can use

```
 let firstViewController:UIViewController = UIViewController()
        // The following statement is what you need
        let customTabBarItem:UITabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "YOUR_IMAGE_NAME"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "YOUR_IMAGE_NAME"))

        firstViewController.tabBarItem = customTabBarItem
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the current `UIViewController`'s tab bar image or title you can access the `tabBarItem` from the `UIViewController` and can change it's properties like this:

```
@IBAction func ChangeTabbarimageAndAction(_ sender: Any) {
    tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "New Image name")
    tabBarItem.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "NewSelectedImageName")
    tabBarItem.title = "New Title"
}
```

Comment: When I declare `tabBarItem` to  `tabBarItem = self.tabBarController!.tabBar.items![0]` I can change image thanks .Also can I add this tabbar a push or present action?

Comment: I think @Jawad has posted an answer for that question you just need to set the delegate for `UITabBarController`. But, was the present controller part asked in your original post?